# VBscript with lists

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to write a VBScript which will read a text file and build a dictionary which contains lists. Let me explain with an example:

The input file would be a simple text file of the sort:

```
Male,Peter
Male,Chris
Male,Stewie
Male,Brian
Female,Lois
Female,Meg
```

When I run my script, I would like a dictionary with the first column as the key, and the second column as the values

```
{'Male':['Peter,Chris,Stewie,Brian']}
{'Female':['Lois,Meg']}
```

The lack of dynamic arrays or lists in VBScript is making this a real pain. Any suggestion how I might tackle this?

Cheers

Comment: Are you trying to build JSON? If so, try out a little lib for it like [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) or (warning: shameless self promotion) a simple JSON utility made by me: https://github.com/rcdmk/aspjson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to say, I'm not compete with posted answers for repo-point ;) 
If you can convert my post to comment, feel free to do that.

I like Ansgar's idea (+1) as it based on single Dictionary and that seems to me quite enough to get back easy what is stored inside.

The need of *.Exists* may come in use in 2 cases - (a) if we don't know how many genders we have, and (b) if we don't know how they looks like (pronunciation). The rest is similar to Ansgar's idea.

```
Option Explicit

Const cGender = 0
Const cName = 1

Dim sGender, sName, sLine
Dim oFSO, oFile, oDict
Dim arrLine

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile("persons_list.txt")

Do Until oFile.AtEndOfStream
    sLine = oFile.ReadLine
    If Len(sLine) Then
        arrLine = Split(sLine, ",")
        sGender = arrLine(cGender)
        sName = arrLine(cName)

        If Not oDict.Exists(sGender) Then
            oDict.Add sGender, CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        End If

        oDict(sGender).Add sName
    End If
Loop

oFile.Close
Set oFile = Nothing
Set oFSO = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Genders:" & oDict.Count, vbNewLine & Join(oDict.Keys)

Dim sKey
For Each sKey In oDict
    WScript.Echo sKey, oDict(sKey).Count, vbNewLine & Join(oDict(sKey).ToArray())
Next
```

Comment: Great, similar idea to the one posted ansgar, wish I could mark both as correct :).

Answer (score 4):

VBScript can use the [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) class provided by the .NET framework.

```
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d.Add "Male", CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
d.Add "Female", CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

d("Male").Add "Peter"
d("Male").Add "Chris"
'...

d("Female").Add "Lois"
d("Female").Add "Meg"
'...
```

For processing the input file take a look at the code provided by @Rich.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the dictionary object, but this might suffice?

```
Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Const cGender = 0
Const cName = 1

Set oFile = oFso.OpenTextFile ("yourfile.txt", 1) 
Do Until oFile.AtEndOfStream
  sLine = oFile.Readline
  If sLine <> "" Then
    arrLine = split(sLine,",")
    oDictionary.Add arrLine(cGender,0), arrLine(cName,0) 'hope i got these indexes the right way round
    'or
    oDictionary.Add arrLine(cGender), arrLine(cName) 'if its one dimentional
  End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Rich approach is faulty (-1) - you can't .Add a key twice and if you could, the names would be overwritten, not appended - and Ansgar's good idea (+1) is not really production ready without a hint wrt its practical use:

```
  Const cGender = 0
  Const cName = 1

  Dim oFS    : Set oFS    = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim dicDic : Set dicDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim dicAl  : Set dicAl  = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim dicCnt : Set dicCnt = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  Dim oFile, sLine, arrLine
  Set oFile = oFS.OpenTextFile ("so14479571.txt")
  Do Until oFile.AtEndOfStream
     sLine = oFile.Readline()
     If sLine <> "" Then
        arrLine = Split(sLine,",")
        dicCnt(arrLine(cGender)) = dicCnt(arrLine(cGender)) + 1

        If Not dicDic.Exists(arrLine(cGender)) Then
           Set dicDic(arrLine(cGender)) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        End If
        dicDic(arrLine(cGender))(arrLine(cName)) = Empty

        If Not dicAl.Exists(arrLine(cGender)) Then
           Set dicAl(arrLine(cGender)) = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        End If
        dicAl(arrLine(cGender)).Add arrLine(cName)
     End If
  Loop
  Dim sKey, sKey2
  WScript.Echo "genders:"
  For Each sKey In dicCnt
      WScript.Echo "", sKey, dicCnt(sKey)
  Next
  WScript.Echo "dic:"
  For Each sKey In dicDic
      WScript.Echo "", sKey
      For Each sKey2 In dicDic(sKey)
          WScript.Echo " ", sKey2
      Next
  Next
  WScript.Echo "AL:"
  For Each sKey In dicAl
      WScript.Echo "", sKey & ":", Join(dicAl(sKey).ToArray())
  Next
```

output:

```
genders:
 Male 4
 Female 2
dic:
 Male
  Peter
  Chris
  Stewie
  Brian
 Female
  Lois
  Meg
AL:
 Male: Peter Chris Stewie Brian
 Female: Lois Meg
```

The script should show:

1. How you can use assignment without .Exists for 'simple' values that can be autovivified (here a number)
2. That you need an .Exists check for values like Arrays, ArrayLists, or Dictionaries

Comment: I don't think your downvote on Rich is justified. He clearly meant the two `.Add` lines to be alternatives (see the comments). I do agree that it would've been better to express the alternatives in a different way, though.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - I disregard the first alternative completely. The problem is that the script fails on the second line of the file with a "key (male) already exists" error. .Add without .Exists check is dangerous.

Comment: True. In this particular situation the best solution would probably be to pre-create the keys to avoid the issue entirely. After all there most likely won't be other genders than "male" and "female".

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - False. Pre-creation and .Add just makes the script fail on the first line.

Comment: How so? AFAICS something like this should work just fine: `arrLine = Split(sLine, ",") : oDictionary(arrLine(0)).Add arrLine(1)`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - True, but Rich's line is 'oDictionary.Add arrLine(cGender), arrLine(cName)'.